# IronPython 2.6 RC2: Cyrillic character and -X:TabCompletion switch

Tags: character-encoding, internationalization, ironpython

Cyrillic characters are displayed incorrect while entering
in interactive mode if interpreter was started with -X:TabCompletion switch.
It looks like that:

> > > s="????"

Answer (score 0):

This is really more of a bug report than a question - you should [file an IronPython issue](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/WorkItem/List.aspx) or ask on [the mailing list](http://lists.ironpython.com/listinfo.cgi/users-ironpython.com).